# Unicode characters getting stored as octets in Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, unicode, apache-pig

I am inserting data into Postgres using Pig's DBStorage. The database encoding is UTF8 and the client encoding is also UTF8. But Postgres is displaying them in octet format

My data as input is `नमस्ते` but when I fire a `SELECT` query on the table, I get `\340\244\250\340\244\256\340\244\270\340\245\215\340\244\244\340\245\207` as the output which is the octet equivalent of the input. My problem is it should be displayed as is.

Any suitable pointers will help

Edit:
My Postgres version is 9.3.6 and The operating System is Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Sounds as if the data got converted on the way _to_ the database.

Comment: What tool are you using to get data from DB?

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko Pig is reading the data from the file. There isn't any issue with Pig. Stuff used to work with MySQL earlier. I am using the command line. No tools as such

Comment: What's the datatype of the column you're getting that from?

Comment: @Daniel I have used varchar which on describe command shows varying character